# Progressive swipe on jQuery Mobile panel

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, panel

I'm developing an application with Phonegap & jQuery Mobile, and it should have a menu panel that can be opened by a swipe gesture. I implemented the code to open it on swipe, but I would like it to be progressive, such as on native apps (facebook, g+ and others...).

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: abu 7maid, what do you mean by progressive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this plugin : https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js
We used that plugin on one of our projects, it works well on iOS phonegap app, on android there are lags.

Comment: Great, that's what I was searching for :)